# Implementation of a particle filter algorithm

Tags: particle-filter, probability

How do you calculate the likelihood of making an observation ?

Does someone have a link to a book or article that explains the math that you need to do to implement a PF algorithm? 
Conceptually i understand the implementation but I'm having a hard time updating the particles after a measurement update. Any resource that goes over the math in details/ with examples would really help.

Answer (score 4):

"Probabilistic Robotics" by Sebastian Thrun, Wolfram Burgard, Dieter Fox is the book you are looking for.

Comment: Can someone explain to me why this was downvoted? I'm interested in improving my answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but I'm here looking at the question and answers now and OP is asking a pretty direct question: "How do you calculate the likelihood of making an observation?" and you're giving them the title of a book. The book might contain the answer, but the title of a book is not the answer.

Comment: "Any resource that goes over the math in details/ with examples would really help".  Probabilistic Robotics is such a resource.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eAqAFSrTGGY) you can find a really interesting video explanation on particle filters.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* nionios. Thanks for your answer but we prefer answers to be self contained where possible. Links [tend to rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) so answers which rely on a link can be rendered useless if the linked content disappears. If you add more context from the link, it is more likely that people will find your answer useful. See [answer] for more info.